# Java Incompatiable Types; JTextField and Integer

Tags: java, swing, integer, jtextfield

For complete code, go to http://ideone.com/7XHxSm

I'm trying to use a `JTextField` then pull the string value then parse the value into an integer. Once parsed, I need to multiply them together. Later on, I will add them all up, add & multiply to get an extra amount, then divide to get a number.

Once you see my code, you'll understand. I know it's a bit cryptic but the code will explain.

I don't know what is going on because I am pulling the value from the `JTextField` then converting it to an integer but Java refuses to convert it.

```
widthWall2 = Integer.parseInteger(wall2Width.getText());
heighthWall2 = Integer.parseInteger(wall2Heighth.getText());
//wall2Area = widthWall2*heighthWall2;
wall2Area = Integer.valueOf(wall2Width.getText()) * integer.valueOf(wall2Heighth.getText());
```

Comment: What type is `wall2Area`?

Comment: I'm not sure what the purpose of the third line is for, but there's a typo on it anyway.  What is Java telling you?  What is the error and where is it complaining?

Comment: Midterm2.java:214: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method parseInteger(java.lang.String)
location: class java.lang.Integer
         widthWall2 = Integer.parseInteger(wall2Width.getText());

Comment: That is the error. wall2Area is the JTextField and I think you just pointed out my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JTextField` and `Integer` are incompatible types so one can't be assigned to the other. You want to set the *content* of the `JTextField. Replace

```
wall2Area = Integer.valueOf(wall2Width.getText()) *
              integer.valueOf(wall2Heighth.getText());
```

with

```
wall2Area.setText(Integer.toString(Integer.valueOf(wall2Width.getText()) * Integer.valueOf(wall2Heighth.getText())));
```

Also, replace

```
Integer.parseInteger(wall2Width.getText())
```

with

```
Integer.parseInt(wall2Width.getText())
```

Always check the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: I realized my problem now. Yes parseInt is what I needed to use but also wall2Area is the JTextField and I needed to use the int version which is areaWall2. Yes, I know they are too similar so don't bust me too bad on that!!

Answer (score 1):

As of the title, I understand the problem is:

```
wall2Area = Integer.valueOf(wall2Width.getText()) *
          integer.valueOf(wall2Heighth.getText());
```

Where you're trying to assign an `Integer` value to a `JTextField`. Change it to:

```
wall2Area.setText(Integer.valueOf(wall2Width.getText()) *
          integer.valueOf(wall2Heighth.getText()));
```